# Multisite authorization error 401

Tags: multisite, authentication

I have created a site on my wordpress network , but when I tried to access the site or dashboard it asks for username and password . Though I didn't create any authorization password (http pass) for my site .  I can access the root site like `example.com` , but the problem only occurs when I try to access the subdomaon like `x.example.com`  . It asks for password , and if I don't give any username or password it shows 401 page with the message

> **Authorization Required**
>
> This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the
>   document requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g.,
>   bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the
>   credentials required.

Answer (score 0):

Look carefully at your .htaccess and apache configuration, Your server is intercepting the request.  Unless I'm mistaken, I really don't think this is a WP problem.  You might try ServerFault.com and/or your host provider for this one.

You also might want to think about how subdomain are mapped to your site. Chances are, if I understand it correctly, you need to specifically map each subdomain to your site with your hoster (if relevant).  For my current host, I also need to set up DNS wildcarding if I don't want to add each subdomain, and I also need to talk to host tech-support to get them to play nicely with the wildcard.

Good luck

Comment: Tried and looked everything , but it doesn't work